# Dr Java; why isnt this compiling?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I would this to know why my program won't compile properly on Dr. Java. Is there something wrong with my code?

Practice Test #1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //reads keyboard input
        System.out.println("please input a string, float or integer"); //asks the user to input into the text field.

        String twine; //names string with variable name of "twine".
        float wood; //names float with variable name of "wood".
        int maths; //names int with the variable name of "maths".


        System.out.println("Please type a string (please input words"); //asks the user to input a sting.
                           twine = sc.nextLine(); // links twine to the entered input
                           System.out.println("Thanks for entering a string" + twine); //displays twine on the screen to siqnify what the user entered


         System.out.println("Please type a float (please input decimal point number"); //asks the user to input a decimal point number.
                           wood = sc.nextFloat(); // links wood to the entered input
                           System.out.println("Thanks for entering a float" + wood); //displays wood on the screen to siqnify what the user entered 



         System.out.println("Please type a int (please input a number"); //asks the user to input a number.
                           maths = sc.nextInt(); // links maths to the entered input
                           System.out.println("Thanks for entering some integer" + maths); //displays maths on the screen to siqnify what the user entered

    }
}
```

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: The code you've shown us compiles. http://ideone.com/xJK74X

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the comments I think it compiles.  Try making sure that your file name is the same as the class name!